# Link A objective C class to story board View controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.3

I started a new IOS app project in Xcode 4.3.1. I selected tabbed application and got a story board with two tabs. I added a new `viewController` to the story board and connected the tab Bar view to new view Controller using relationship. I now see 3 tabs in simulator. Now i created subclass on `UIViewController`. I want to link this subclass to the new view controller I added to story board so that I can do something on `viewDidLoad`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly set your Custom class on IB.

Screenshot:

[image]